# application.html.erb where line #6 raised: TypeError: Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm facing the following error message:

> ExecJS::ProgramError in Restaurantes#index
>   Showing C:/rubyProject/vota_prato/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where >line #6 raised:
>
> TypeError: O objeto não dá suporte para a propriedade ou método
>   Rails.root: C:/rubyProject/vota_prato
>
> Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
>   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:6:in >`_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__971963449_62998908'
>   Request

I fixed it removing the line:

> true %>

from my app/views/layouts/application.html.erb file

after I did it, I faced the other problem =(. I created a action destroy at one controller:

```
class RestaurantesController < ApplicationController
    def destroy
        @restaurante = Restaurante.find(params[:id])
        @restaurante.destroy
        redirect_to(action: "index")
    end

    def index
        @restaurantes = Restaurante.all
    end

    def show
        @restaurante = Restaurante.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

and my index.html.rb file:

```
<h1>Listagem de Restaurantes</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Nome</th>
    <th>Endereço</th>
    <th>Especialidade</th>
  </tr>

<% @restaurantes.each do |restaurante| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= restaurante.id %></td>
    <td><%= restaurante.nome %></td>
    <td><%= restaurante.endereco %></td>
    <td><%= restaurante.especialidade %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Mostrar', action: 'show', id: restaurante %></td>
    <td>--</td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Deletar', {action: 'destroy', id: restaurante},{method: "delete"} %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

when clicked at Deletar link, it executed same action as Show action, I don't know why

Answer (score 7):

To solve the ExecJS problem in Windows, change the parameter `application` to `default` in lines 5 and 6 of the **views/layouts/aplication.html.erb** file.

The file should look like this:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'default', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'default', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, I'm sorry for my english if it's too bad...
This error happened to me a couple months ago. There wasn't a problem with ruby, rails gem, or any other gem installed.

These are my specs:

- Running Windows 10
- Using RubyInstaller 3.2.0, packages included are:

  - Ruby 2.2.4
  - Rails 4.2
  - Bundler
  - Git
  - Sqlite
  - TinyTDS
  - SQL Server Support
  - DevKit

After insalling the RubyInstaller, I created a new project, but I had the same error like you:

```
ExecJS::ProgramError in home#index Showing C:/ruby_project/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #6 raised:
TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method
```

**DEFINITE SOLUTION IS:**

1. Stop any rails web server.
2. Close everything.
3. Open your web browser and surf onto nodejs download packages site OR you can download it from here:
   [Download Link (Windows)](https://nodejs.org/dist/v4.4.5/node-v4.4.5-x86.msi)
4. Install nodejs on your Operative System. Install the 32-bit version, even if you're running on 64-bit.
5. Restart your computer, open a command line to your desired project, and then run 'rails server'.
6. Done... Don't need to change anything on app/views/layouts/application.html.erb. **IT WILL WORK**... just let it by default:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Sample</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

**NOTE: For linux/mac users, just install ruby and rails by RVM (Ruby Version Manager). You won't have any problem, I tell you this by experience.**

For installing RVM on your linux/mac terminal I will recommend you these tutorials below. I've tried them and they work!

- How-to: [Install RVM For Linux Users (Debian Distributions)](http://railsapps.github.io/installrubyonrails-ubuntu.html)
- How-to: [Install RVM for Mac Users](http://railsapps.github.io/installrubyonrails-mac.html)

Please comment if this worked for you or not...

Regards.

Comment: Yes. I'm using Rails 5.1.4, Ruby 2.3.3 & Bundler 1.16.0. My issue resolved with installation of nodejs. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Can't tell much about your JS problem because not enough information.

As for the link part, your delete link should look like this:

```
<%= link_to 'Deletar', restaurante_path(restaurante), method: :delete %>
```

Also make sure that you have `jquery-ujs` included in your `application.js` (this is what understands the `method: :delete` part in your link and POSTs a form rather than GETting a page)

*BTW, do not ask two question in one. Make them separate questions.*

Answer (score 1):

You need to install nodejs to fuse the turbolliks; )

Follow the link: https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Comment: You may want to expand your answer to say why node is required to compile turbolinks to get the jquery_ujs or rails_ujs deletion feature :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you uncommented the line:

```
gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby
```

from your gemfile? Do that, run "bundle install" and try again. The delete method relies on some Javascript. It's rubyracer or some nodejs thing you can use instead, I can't remoember what it is called.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, it works, but I think it worked because I installed the nodeJS. After I restarted my computer, however both solutions worked

Comment: Yeah nodejs will do the job also, glad it works for you!